# How can I find which JNI library implements a java native method at runtime for Android applications?

Tags: android, reverse-engineering

I am doing security research, my target application includes some JNI libraries which implements some native java methods I am interested in. This app is obfuscated, I can't directly find the library by unpacking the APK archive.

Searching on the Web I found I can use ART's [GetNativeMethods()](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/main/+/refs/heads/main:art/runtime/native_bridge_art_interface.cc;drc=e759826803f67ead26354fbcaf746ec6d74e178f;l=56) from a JNI function, then use the native method's JNI pointer to find the shared library where it is located. But ART is a private API and latest Android versions block the loading of `libart.so`, I can't use it.

I am using Xposed to instrument the target application at runtime.

Comment: I think you will have better luck on the reverseengineering stackexchange.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I think my question is very clear, it's exactly the title of the post...